# table-cell not filling div when sibling has overflown

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

See reference: http://codepen.io/RuttyJ/pen/oxxvrL
When the screen is very tiny the two divs change height when overflow. I would like the two divs to always be the same height no matter what without the use of `<table>`.

```
.splash_row{
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
}
.splash_col.half{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
.splash_inside{
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Edit:
I hope to fill the parent column completely without haveing to bump-up or down the min-height of the contained elements. I know Javascript can do this but can CSS3 do it by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `min-height` property to the div with the class `.splash_col_content`. It would look like this:

`.splash_col_text {
    min-height: 56px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 12px;
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.35, 0.58,
}`

Ideally, you would place that CSS inside this media query so it's only loaded on screens under 500px: `@media (max-width: 500px).`

Codepen: http://codepen.io/kristywessel/pen/KzzKeP

Comment: Yes that works, but I was hoping to resolve this so that it would always fill the remainder of the parent without coding for a specific case.